# No source map when deploying a Create React App to Netlify

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, netlify

Deploying to Netlify using `create-react-app`.

#### Issue:

- **Not** build the source map for production deploy.
- Have the source map for other builds for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution:

Add the `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP` `env` variable to flag no source map. Edit the `netlify.toml` to include the variable for use in build contexts.

`netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  publish = "build"

[build.environment]
  GENERATE_SOURCEMAP = "true"

[build.production.environment]
  GENERATE_SOURCEMAP = "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using netlify.toml you can also use Environment Variables to set

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP = false
```

in your site settings->Build & Deploy -> Environment

Here is the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPOkt.png)

Comment: The reason I don't use this method is because your answer only gives one value choice. The solution I gave is setup to give a source map for deploy-previews and branch deploys to have a source map for debugging. While during production builds it doesn't create a source map.

Comment: You can add this to netlify's production build only and for all other builds it will generate the source map

Comment: Yes, I definitely know how it works. I'm trying to explain that your assumption here is incorrect. This would set the value for all build contexts and require checking in code for the build context. I just don't want someone who is new to misunderstand how the build context works.